# Dockerize Python scripts that have common code base

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize multiple Python scripts that use common code base (classes etc)

This is the files tree:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── libs
│   ├── lib1.dylib
├── logs
├── requirements.txt
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── alias.py
│   ├── db
│   │   └── First.db
│   │   └── Second.db
│   ├── exceptions.py
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── keywords.json
│   │   ├── proxies.txt
│   │   └── user_agents.txt
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── monitor.py
│   ├── sites
│   │   ├── First
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── first.py
│   │   ├── Second
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── second.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── database.py
│       ├── functions.py
│       ├── http_requests
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── proxy_manager.py
│       │   └── user_agent_manager.py
│       ├── paths.py
│       └── product.py
```

What I want to do is use Docker compose to run `first.py` and `second.py` knowing that they both use the same code base and environnement and other files too. They'll also share access to db folder and files.

I tried this to begin:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10.10-bullseye
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir /monitors
ADD . /monitors
WORKDIR /monitors
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY src/sites/First/first.py ./
COPY src/sites/Second/second.py ./
```

```
version: '3'
services:
  first:
    build: ./
    command: python3 -m src.sites.First.first
  second:
    build: ./
    command: python3 -m src.sites.Second.second
```

But it doesn't seem to work (Stuck on Attaching to ...)

I'd also like to know if there is any better way to do this

Comment: That seems fine (assuming `src` is in fact part of the module name).  When you say "it doesn't work", what does happen?

Comment: @DavidMaze I just edited my question, it stays stuck on Attaching to ...

Comment: From your compose file, you are setting up two containers, Your command will not running on the same place. and what do you mean is not working? Any logs?